# How to safely dismiss DialogFragment in onstop()?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I need to dismiss DialogFragment in onStop() of an FragmentActivity if it is showing, this is what I did

```java
if(mAlertDlg != null && mAlertDlg.getDialog() != null)
    mAlertDlg.dismiss();
```

But I usually got IllegalStateException. So please tell me why that code is wrong and what is the correct way to dismiss DialogFragment in onStop()? Thank you.

Comment: See this [**blog post**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) about this topic for more information. In general you don't want to use the `*****AllowingStateLoss()` methods to address issues like this. The `IllegalStateException` is thrown because state loss will occur. Using these methods are just avoiding the exception... but the state loss will still remain likely causing a bug in your application.

Comment: Thank you for that nice article but in my scenario I still can find a better way than using *AllowingStateLoss() method to dismiss dialog when Activity is not in foreground anymore. Can't dismiss() on onPause() and onStop() so what should I do?

Comment: The FragmentManager will dismiss the dialog automatically when the activity goes into the background and/or is finished. I can't see why it would be necessary to dismiss the dialog in onStop()... By that point the FragmentManager has saved the state of its Fragments and recorded it all as part of the Activity's state, so the dismiss call will have no effect. Either way, neither dialogs nor fragments can persist across multiple Activity instances... They will be removed from the Activity's window either way once the Activity is stopped/destroyed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use `dialogFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss()`. As the documentation say for `commitAllowingStateLoss()`:

> "Like commit() but allows the commit to be executed after an
>   activity's state is saved. This is dangerous because the commit can be
>   lost if the activity needs to later be restored from its state, so
>   this should only be used for cases where it is okay for the UI state
>   to change unexpectedly on the user."

So for `dismissAllowingStateLoss()` is the same approach.

Comment: You can also check this **[post](https://medium.com/inloop/demystifying-androids-commitallowingstateloss-cb9011a544cc)** for more info about `commitAllowingStateLoss()` and `dismissAllowingStateLoss()`.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to dismiss a `DialogFragment` in `onStop()`, you probably don't want to use a `DialogFragment` but a classic `Dialog` instead.

The reason why `DialogFragment` exists is to allow a dialog to be restored automatically when the Activity is re-created. If you dismiss it in `onStop()`, it will never be restored.

Also, if you use `dismissAllowingStateLoss()`, the dismiss transaction may not be recorded properly in `onSaveInstanceState()` (as the name says, a state loss may occur), and this will result in the dialog being restored when the activity is re-created, and obviously that's not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`dismissAllowingStateLoss()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#dismissAllowingStateLoss%28%29) instead of `dismiss()`.